# Is my piecewise function right? Problem given below.

Tags: functions

Problem:
A computer shop charges 20 pesos per hour (or a fraction of an hour) for the first two hours and an additional 10 pesos per hour for each succeeding hour. Represent your computer rental fee using the function R(t) where t is the number of hours you spent on the computer.

My answer:
$$R(t) = \cases{20 \text{ pesos}  & if $0 <t\le 2$\cr
({t-2}) \cdot 10 \text{ pesos}  +40 \text{ pesos} & if $t>2$}$$

Please correct me if I have any mistake.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you the right way, it should be $ R \colon \Bbb{N} \to \Bbb{N} $

$$R(t) = \cases{20 {t} & if $0 \le t \le 2$\cr
10({t-2}) +40 & if $t>2$}$$
where $R(t)$ is in pesos. 
However this can be a misunderstanding of your first sentence. I think your mistake then would be that he charges 20 pesos per hour in the first two hours that would be 20 pesos each and a total of 40 pesos for two hours.

Comment: The problem above is exactly the same problem written on my textbook. I thought about what you said too. The first sentence confuses me.

Comment: Okay, so i am pretty sure that its 20 pesos times t. Further should your function only allow integer values or should it be a function of real numbers?  Am i allowed to evaluate $R(1.5)$?